# How do I set automatic turn off on XenServer?

Tags: virtual-machine, xen

I want to turn daily my XenServer off on 21pm and turn it on on 6am. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

set up a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job